# View Intermediate Language code in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, cil

I want to see the IL code for my C# code in Visual Studio.

The only way I have found to do this, is by the command line tool ildasm.exe, but this tool has a very rudimentary UI.

Here is an example of ildasm.exe showing the IL for a simple console app.

[image]

Is there a way to view that *within* VS 2022? Are there any native windows, that one could bind to a hotkey, to show the IL for C# code? Similar to how you would show a class definition when you press F12 on a class.

Comment: ReSharper (and Jetbrains Rider) have a [IL Viewer](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Viewing_Intermediate_Language.html) that can do what you want. I don't think there's anything similar built in to VS.

Comment: I'm not aware of anything built-in VS. But there are several free tools with nice UI. One of the most popular is [ILSpy](https://github.com/icsharpcode/ILSpy). And it has a [VS 2022 extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SharpDevelopTeam.ILSpy2022).

Comment: I released an answer in combination with the comments. If it helps you, you can make its mark so that it can help more people

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, Visual Studio currently does not have a built-in tool for viewing C# IL code.

But there are some extensions that can view C#'s IL code, such as [ReSharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Viewing_Intermediate_Language.html), [ILSpy](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items%20?itemName=SharpDevelopTeam.ILSpy2022)